# press buttons on gamepad

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico, gamepad, adafruit-circuitpython

i am trying to press buttons on the gamepad i am using a gamepad descriptor for the gamepad but i cant find out how to press the buttons on the gamepad is there any way to press the buttons? i am using an raspberry pi pico for this

```
import usb_hid

GAMEPAD_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR = bytes((
    0x05, 0x01,  # Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
    0x09, 0x05,  # Usage (Game Pad)
    0xA1, 0x01,  # Collection (Application)
    0x85, 0x04,  #   Report ID (4)
    0x05, 0x09,  #   Usage Page (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,  #   Usage Minimum (Button 1)
    0x29, 0x20,  #   Usage Maximum (Button 32)
    0x15, 0x00,  #   Logical Minimum (0)
    0x25, 0x01,  #   Logical Maximum (1)
    0x75, 0x01,  #   Report Size (1)
    0x95, 0x20,  #   Report Count (32)
    0x81, 0x02,  #   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
    0x05, 0x01,  #   Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
    0x15, 0x81,  #   Logical Minimum (-127)
    0x25, 0x7F,  #   Logical Maximum (127)
    0x09, 0x30,  #   Usage (X)
    0x09, 0x31,  #   Usage (Y)
    0x09, 0x32,  #   Usage (Z)
    0x09, 0x35,  #   Usage (Rz)
    0x75, 0x08,  #   Report Size (8)
    0x95, 0x04,  #   Report Count (4)
    0x81, 0x02,  #   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
    0xC0,        # End Collection
))

gamepad = usb_hid.Device(
    report_descriptor=GAMEPAD_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR,
    usage_page=0x01,           # Generic Desktop Control
    usage=0x05,                # Gamepad
    report_ids=(4,),           # Descriptor uses report ID 4.
    in_report_lengths=(12,),    # This gamepad sends 6 bytes in its report.
    out_report_lengths=(0,),   # It does not receive any reports.
)

usb_hid.enable(
    (usb_hid.Device.KEYBOARD,
     usb_hid.Device.MOUSE,
     usb_hid.Device.CONSUMER_CONTROL,
     gamepad)
)
```

i am using this code to create the gamepad it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The report descriptor tells the host which reports your device supports, but your device still has to actually compose and send those reports.

It looks like you're using the report descriptor from AdaFruit's [Custom HID Devices in CircuitPython](https://learn.adafruit.com/custom-hid-devices-in-circuitpython/report-descriptors). If you keep reading, the [next section](https://learn.adafruit.com/custom-hid-devices-in-circuitpython/radial-controller) shows how to implement a "Radial Controller". It doesn't matter that it's a Radial Controller and not a Gamepad, it's a good enough starting point.

The code to compose and send the Radial Controller's input report lives here:

[https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Radial_Controller/blob/cbf0136014f08356cc7b7c2b65964bdff3e394b8/adafruit_radial_controller/\_\_init\_\_.py#L37](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Radial_Controller/blob/cbf0136014f08356cc7b7c2b65964bdff3e394b8/adafruit_radial_controller/%5C_%5C_init%5C_%5C_.py#L37)

The main difference is the RadialController only has one axis (the rotation angle) and one button. We can confirm this from the RadialController's report descriptor:

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Radial_Controller/blob/cbf0136014f08356cc7b7c2b65964bdff3e394b8/adafruit_radial_controller/device.py#L30

The report descriptor says the input report starts with 1 bit for a button, then 7 bits of padding, then a 16-bit field for a Dial input. That means the report should have 3 bytes: 1 byte for the button + padding, then 2 bytes for the Dial input.

In [RadialController._send()](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Radial_Controller/blob/cbf0136014f08356cc7b7c2b65964bdff3e394b8/adafruit_radial_controller/__init__.py#L90) we can see how the report buffer is composed with the `pressed` state in the first byte and `rotation` in the next two bytes:

```
    def _send(self, pressed, rotation):
        self.report[0] = int(pressed)
        self.report[1] = rotation & 0xFF
        self.report[2] = (rotation >> 8) & 0xFF

        self._controller.send_report(self.report)
```

You'll need to modify this to match the format defined in the Gamepad report descriptor.

Comment: ive tried using an radial controller but the issue is that it doesnt show in game controllers for what i am using it for i need it to show up in game controllers and have multiple buttons and axis

Comment: If you're starting from RadialController make sure you update `usage_page` to 1 and `usage` to 5. The Usage Page and Usage tell the operating system what type of device it is; usage 5 from usage page 1 is "Game Pad". The report descriptor tells which buttons and axes it has.